# Angular in ajax $scope to return String

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm a new enter of AngularJs, and my question like this:

```
$scope.checkActDate = function(){
    var remoteService =$http({
        method : 'POST'
        url : "../checkActDateChm803.action",
    data: {actDate:$scope.ch803FVo.actDate},
        dataType: "json",
        headers:{'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type':'application/json; ; charset=UTF-8'} 
    });
    remoteService.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {    
        return data.responseVo;
    })
};

var check = $scope.checkActDate();
if(check != "0"){
    return true;
}
```

For now, I got the `return data.responseVo` is a `String "0"`,
and I know the `$scope.checkActDate` is a object, but I have no idea and my question is
how could I `return data.responseVo` and `var check` can get String "0" ?

thanks a lot...

Comment: What do you mean exactly? How to check which type the response is? Eg. `if ( typeof check === 'object' ) { /* do something */ }`?

Comment: check is object but I want change check=`$scope.checkActDate()` to the `data.reponseVo`'s value in function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http` request is an asynchronous request, so rather than returning data on success you should store it inside scope variable. Like

```
remoteService.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {    
    $scope.data = data.responseVo;
})
```

Now you can perform a check on `$scope.data`

```
if($scope.data != "0"){
    // Do your stuff here
}
```